# CSS indentation not working

Tags: html, css

Can someone give me an idea how indent the text here in CSS (CLICK HERE) as shown here:

So it indented as shown in the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="aText">
    <div>Test One 01</div>
    <div>CLICK HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="aText">
    <div>Test Two</div>
    <div>CLICK HERE</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.aText {
font-size: 10px;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-indent:15px;
}
```

Here is my working progress: http://jsfiddle.net/qz3GF/

Edited: Yes I could use text-indent but then again the other right text (Test Two > CLICK HERE) Will also indented which I dont intend to do.

Comment: Use `text-indent` property

Comment: Just correct the syntax and it will work: (margin:2px;) Rgds,

Comment: I have tried to use `text-indent` but the whole (CLICK HERE) on the right side aslo move which isnt right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could apply css margin to the divs containing only the lines you want indented (with a larger margin than the .atext div)

Comment: I tried this:

HTML:
`<div class="aText">
    <div>Test One 01</div>
    <div class="indent">CLICK HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="aText">
    <div>Test Two</div>
    <div>CLICK HERE</div>
</div>'

CSS:  
`div.indent{
 text-indent:30px;

}`
Actually it worked - but it seems to me a bit messy - I was wondering if there is better way to do it?

Comment: change div.indent{text-indent:20px;} to
    div.indent{margin-left:20px}

Comment: thanks..i think both of that worked well - just thinking if there is better way to do it - but thanks for the inputs!

Comment: Other options would be using a table to space everything to way you want it or apply a width or max-width to each div if you're having problems with the margin moving other elements

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your CSS: should be **margin:2px;** instead of margin;2px;